# a href link won't work on image

Tags: html, css, href

I need a little help...
I can't understand why my links on my images won't work...
I have been searching for so long time, but i can't find the reason why it won't work! Please help me...
Thank you so much!

```css
.container {
 width: 80%;
 max-width: 1240px; /*maks bredde*/
 min-height: 500px;
 margin: 0 auto; /*midtstiller container og setter den øverst*/
}


header {
 background-color: #292929;
 width: 80%;
 position: fixed;
 margin-top: 5px;
}


header img{
 width: 8%;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 height: 4%;
}


#navlogoer {
 width: 40%;
 margin-left: 75%;
 margin-top: -65px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <header>
        <a href="index.html">
            <img src="images/Opheimlogooransje.png" alt="opheim logo"/></a>
        <nav id="navlogoer">
            <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/no/album/summerbeach-feat.-tiril-sundf/id981300584?i=981300598&uo=6&at=&ct=">
                <img src="images/ITuneslogocroped.png" alt="Itunes logo"/></a>
            <a href="https://open.spotify.com/artist/0VaCp9BRPhNezjr5Z3va5l">
                <img src="images/Spotifylogocroped.png" alt="Spotify logo"/></a>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCohhdrYONwzIeMW61Ibgszw/feed">
                <img src="images/youtubelogocroped.png" alt="Youtube logo"/></a>
            <a href="https://soundcloud.com/jesperopheim">
                <img src="images/Soundcloudlogocroped.png" alt="Soundcloud"/></a>
            <a href="https://no.7digital.com/artist/opheim/">
                <img src="images/7digitallogocroped.png" alt="7digital logo"/></a>
        </nav>
    </header>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to link some url while clicking on an image?

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, all the links are working fine. Actually the correct syntax for making the images as links is as follows:

```
<pre><code><a href="#"><img src="" alt="" /></a></code></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you have done something wrong here

```
header img{
    width: 8%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    height: 4%;
}
```

Change it as

```
header a{
    width: 8%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    height: 4%;
display:block;
}
```

and

```
header img{
    width: 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, I checked.

Here is sample [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcn5kod0/)

I just replaced images only.

So you check the location of your images.

```
<div class="container">

<header>
    <a href="index.html">
        <img src="http://s17.postimg.org/ahbud601n/klematis2.jpg" alt="opheim logo"/></a>


        <nav id="navlogoer">
            <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/no/album/summerbeach-feat.-tiril-sundf/id981300584?i=981300598&uo=6&at=&ct=">
                <img src="images/ITuneslogocroped.png" alt="Itunes logo"/></a>
            <a href="https://open.spotify.com/artist/0VaCp9BRPhNezjr5Z3va5l">
            <img src="images/Spotifylogocroped.png" alt="Spotify logo"/></a>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCohhdrYONwzIeMW61Ibgszw/feed">
                <img src="http://s17.postimg.org/ahbud601n/klematis2.jpg" alt="Youtube logo"/></a>
            <a href="https://soundcloud.com/jesperopheim">
                <img src="http://s17.postimg.org/ahbud601n/klematis2.jpg" alt="Soundcloud"/></a>
            <a href="https://no.7digital.com/artist/opheim/">
                <img src="http://s17.postimg.org/ahbud601n/klematis2.jpg" alt="7digital logo"/></a>
                </nav>
                </header>        

</div>

</body>
</html>
```